# Split text rows in dataframe into paragraphs and keep document id - python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a pd dataframe with rows containing document, their respective ids. I would like to split each document into paragraphs while keeping their respective ids:

```
ORIGINAL DATAFRAME

data={'id':['1','2','3'], 'doc':['Paragraph 1.\nParagraph 2.\nParagraph 3.', 'Paragraph 1.\nParagraph 2.', 'Paragraph 1.\nParagraph 2.\nParagraph 3.\nParagraph 4.']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (one paragraph per row with respective id)

```
id    doc                                             
           
1     paragraph 1.                             
1     paragraph 2.                              
1     paragraph 3.                              
2     paragraph 1.                              
2     paragraph 2.                        
3     paragraph 1.                              
3     paragraph 2.                              
3     paragraph 3.                              
3     paragraph 4.
```

I have the following function:

```
def split_into_paragraphs(dataframe): 
    
    docs = dataframe.to_json(orient="records")
    paragraphs: List[str] = []
    doc_indices: List[str] = []

    for doc in docs:         
        for para in range(len(doc)):
            paragraphs.append(str(doc[para].split("\n")))
            doc_indices = doc_indices + [doc["id"]]

    return (doc_indices, paragraphs)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:path.ipynb Cellule 32 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df2 = split_into_paragraphs(df)

c:path.ipynb in split_into_paragraphs(dataframe)
      8     for para in range(len(doc)):
      9         paragraphs.append(str(doc[para].split("\n")))
---> 10         doc_indices = doc_indices + [doc["id"]]
     12 return (doc_indices, paragraphs)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Since I am new to python, I am having problems figuring out what to do. I am not sure if it is a problem with the function in itself or with how I am calling it:

```
df2 = df.apply(split_into_paragraphs)
```

A final note that might be important: in my real dataframe, ids can also be a combination of numbers and words (instead of numbers only).

I would appreciate your help figuring out this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing a code to reproduce your `df`. You could use the `apply` function to call a `lambda` function that does what you need, for instance:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n').explode())
```

This `lambda` function will split the strings wherever it finds `\n` and it will [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) it to new rows.

Comment: It is perfect and so much simpler! It worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the first rows of this df?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand what is it that you would like to do. With the example `df` that you gave, when using `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n').explode())` it explodes normally and repeats the values for all the other columns except `doc` where it separates the paragraphs